# Added a folder to www. Appears as Folder structure on browser

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, redirect

A buddy of my mind developed an image viewer for a website. I have this web server that already contains a www/WebDev folder where all development work is done.

The image viewer has its own folder and file called viewer.php  with its own Images folder and css and scripts. I Simply want to append the folder to the WebDev directory and see that everything runs correctly.
When I type WebDev/Viewer I should get the the webpage for the viewer (viewer.php)

**The Problem**

When I do so, I get an indexing of all the directories and files in WebDev.

How come the website displays directories instead of the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn of indexing in .htaccess in the root. Put this at the top.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Additionally you can create an `.htaccess` file in `/WebDev/Viewer/` and in it put this.

```
DirectoryIndex viewer.php
```

That should make it the default page for /Viewer.